# MS Access front end able to log in Cross-domain with SQL Authentication to 2008 instance, but not 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, cross-domain, sql-authentication

I have a Microsoft Access front-end application that can log in (cross-domain) with SQL authentication just fine to a SQL Server 2008 instance, but is not able to log in to a SQL Server 2012 instance.

Is there a difference in the network protocols?  I haven't been able to find anything.

Regarding the 2012 instance, does TCP/IP need to be first in the configuration manager?  Shared Memory is first, and enabled...named pipes are also enabled.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Yes, I do, but the problem turned out to be that MS Access retained the old connection even when you told it to use the new connection.  I had to go into the Linked Table manager and use the advanced settings, then it worked.